# Cleanest way to declare env vars with Express

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to find out there the best solution about how to store environment vars for Node using Express. Many tutorials suggest to move the data into a .json file, [here is an example](http://himanshu.gilani.info/blog/2012/09/26/bootstraping-a-node-dot-js-app-for-dev-slash-prod-environment/) but the don't config environment vars, they define new vars such as:

```
{
    "test": {
        "facebook_app_id": "facebook_dummy_dev_app_id",
        "facebook_app_secret": "facebook_dummy_dev_app_secret",
    }, 
    "development": {
        "facebook_app_id": "facebook_dummy_dev_app_id",
        "facebook_app_secret": "facebook_dummy_dev_app_secret",
    }, 
    "production": {
        "facebook_app_id": "facebook_dummy_prod_app_id",
        "facebook_app_secret": "facebook_dummy_prod_app_secret",
    }
}
```

The problem I've find to this approach is that I can't define vars in it, because all elements must be inside double quotes ( " ) so I can't do:

```
{
    process.env.PORT = 3000,
    process.env.NODE_APP = XXX
    ....
}
```

I've tried to do some tricky things like defining a `.js` file and store there the vars, something like this:

module.exports = {
    env: {
        USER:"www-data",
        NODE_ENV:"development",
        PORT:"3002",
        ....
        LOG_FILE:"error.log"
    }
}

In this case, I have not found the way to use those vars inside env, something like:

```
module.exports = {
    env: {
        ...
        process.env.APP_NAME:"application.name",
        process.env.NODEJS_DIR:"/var/nodejs",
        process.env.APP_DIR: `${this.NODEJS_DIR}/${this.APP_NAME}/current`, //Not working
        process.env.APP_DIR:process.env.NODEJS_DIR}/${this.APP_NAME}/current`, //Not working, and verbose, ugly code
        ....
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: why would you need "${this.NODEJS_DIR}/${this.APP_NAME}/current" as a var? did you try make use of '__dirname' ?

Comment: Assigning properties to `process.env` is not the correct way to declare envrionment variables. You need to declare them on the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) module to achieve this.

So in your root directory, create 2 files (depending on how many different environments you might have) named `development.env` and `production.env`

In your app, do this:

```
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
require('dotenv').config({
    path: './' + env + '.env'
});
```

Then you could access all the environment variables you have defined in the respective env file.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this you are looking for.

```
app.configure('production', function(){

// production env. specific settings 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

As another example of forming the config file

```
// config file in /config/general.js
var path = require('path'),
    rootPath = path.normalize(__dirname + '/..'),
    env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

    if (env == 'development') {
      process.env.DEBUG = 'http';
    }

var config = {
  development: {
    name : 'development',
    root: rootPath,
    port: 3000
  },

  production: {
    name : 'prod',
    root: rootPath,
    port: 3000
  }
};

module.exports = config[env];
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about the dev-ops team, how they will deploy your software? They won't touch the code, and the configuration file should not contain any logic. So the `.js` file containing configurations is wrong. You have to provide them an interface to configure the execution. That may be a parameter, or if the configuration is complex, then it should be extracted to a configuration file.

My approach is to load `app.json` by default. If the dev-ops engeneer provides `NODE_ENV=customenv`, then load `app.customenv.json` configuration file. This way the `.json` file won't expose non-relevant development configurations to the users.

`APP_NAME` is not part of the environment, but part of your software configuration. This parameter should be configured in the .json configuration file.

Directories can be relevant to the software directory, it defined in the `__dirname` variable.

The `app.json` file should be loaded by a configuration module. You can use one of the open-source projects available, for example `nconf`.